# setting a value with jquery, removes the binding to the ViewModel when the data is submitted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have checkbox option that after I check it, I change the value of an input field that shows only a Month and Year. In the case the checkbox is not selected. The user clicks on the input and a datepicker gives the option to choose the date(Month/Year). With the first option the values are not posted correctly, with the second yes. What I am doing wrong?

[image]

Unchecking year to Date and clicking on the input instead

[image]

Now if I check the (year to date) and post the value then startDate end endDate have a null value.

My Controller is as follow

```
    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(ManualRecViewModel vm)
```

My ViewModel has field startDate and EndDate

```
public class ManualRecViewModel
{
        public DateTime? startDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? endDate { get; set; }
}
```

and my View is

```
    <div class="input-group">
        <div>
            @Html.CheckBox("year-to-date", false)
            @Html.Label("Year to Date")
        </div>

        <div class="dates-filters">
            <div>
                @Html.Label("From:")
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.startDate, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.Label("To:")
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.endDate, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have a js that set the values to the input

```
    var date = new Date();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    $("#startDate").datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, 0, 1));
    $("#endDate").datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the values passed into your controller, using JS? You'll likely find that the final date values are invalid and a model binding issue will occur.

Comment: I am not posting the values with js, the inputs are inside a form with a submit button

Comment: What is your `CultureInfo` ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before and found that using the `$.trigger("change")` method is needed, because using set and `$.val()` methods don't actually cause the input fields value to change for the form submission

Comment: actually my function is for the change event of the checkbox $("#year-to-date").change(yearToDate); but how can I do it for the inputs?

Comment: What I'm saying is after you do the `$.setDate()` call you should also call `$("#startDate, #endDate").trigger("change")` to get the date inputs to finalize the change

Comment: The other option would be in your C# server code, check if the user select YTD check box, and if they did just ignore the dates submitted then and determine YTD on the server

Comment: the question here is for the resolve the issue on the client side, and rely on the model binding of MVC, I can make the workaround on the server, but that is not the proper way because even then, if there is something wrong with another field and I display the errors, the model that will be displayed will not have startDate end endDate at least I hardcode that part. Your advise on using trigger("change") didn't work for me